# How to fetch Data from Database into angular form select?

Tags: django, angular, postgresql

I am working on a CRUD App. I want to display values in `<select>` from Database table instead of specifying them in the `<option>`. I have manually created a country table in Database, I want the values from the DB to displayed as drop-down instead manually specifying them to `<select>`, `<option>`.

[image: Dropdown]

I have created the app with Angular(frontend), PostgreSQL(Database) and Django(backend).
Here is the Repository: [GitHub](https://github.com/purushottamnawale/Tax-Authority-CRUD) |
https://github.com/purushottamnawale/Tax-Authority-CRUD

**app.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Tax } from './Tax';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaxService {
  private url: string = 'http://localhost:8000/api/taxapp/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addTax(tax: Tax): Observable<Tax> {
    return this.http.post<Tax>(this.url, tax);
  }

  getTaxes(): Observable<Tax[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tax[]>(this.url);
  }
  
  getTax(id: number): Observable<Tax> {
    return this.http.get<Tax>(`${this.url}${id}`);
  }
  
  getCountry(): Observable<Tax[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tax[]>(this.url); // Need modification here
  }

  updateTax(id: number, tax: Tax): Observable<Tax> {
    return this.http.put<Tax>(`${this.url}${id}/`, tax);
  }

  deleteTax(id: number): Observable<Tax> {
    return this.http.delete<Tax>(`${this.url}${id}/`);
  }

}
```

**add-tax.component.html snippet:**

```
<!--Need modification here-->
<div class="col form-group">
    <label for="taxtype" class="form-label">Country Name</label>
    <select class="form-select" data-style="btn-primary" formControlName="country" name="country" id="country">
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
    </select>
</div> 


<!--
<div class="col form-group">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label for="taxtype">Country Name</mat-label>
        <mat-select formControlName="country" name="country" id="country">
            <mat-option value="India">India</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="USA">USA</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div> -->
```

**add-tax.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TaxService } from 'src/app/app.service';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatSlideToggleChange } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-tax',
  templateUrl: './add-tax.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-tax.component.css']
})
export class AddTaxComponent {

  constructor(private service: TaxService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  data: any

  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    country: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    taxtype: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    zone: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    ward: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    status: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });

  addTax() {
    this.data = this.form.value;
    this.service.addTax(this.data).subscribe(data => {
      // redirect to home page
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }
}
```

**models.py in Django:**

```
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Create your models here
class Tax(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    taxtype = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    zone=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    ward=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Edit: I have found a solution to my problem. The implementation can be found on GitHub [Repository](https://github.com/purushottamnawale/Tax-Authority-CRUD).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the official way of specifying dropdown options in [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview).
What are you missing, is FormControlName attribute on mat-select.